# Pass additional input to custom validation profile in SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email

Tags: rest, azure-ad-b2c

How to pass additional input parameter ( other than username, password) to custom validationtechnicalprofile ( REST API) in SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email profile or Is there a way to query the AD using entered username/email and get extra fields and pass them to validation profile to perform some more extra work in REST API

Comment: Can you please clarify what you might want to pass, in addition to username and password, to the REST API?

Comment: As part of Pre-migration of user from our data store, we are planning to store the migration status flag as well in azure ad b2c, so when the user logs in we wanted to query the azure AD to get the status (along with username and password) and pass that to API to see if the username and password should be validated by REST API or not ( storing that flag outside of of azure b2c is not an option we are looking for since 4.5 m users and wanted to get rid off the On-premise data store)

Comment: @ChrisPadgett - I even tried to call the graph api from REST API( since I couldn't get the additional claims from B2) but it seems the call to AcquireTokenAsync hangs